# How to secure delegate instance reference

Tags: c#, delegates

In the perspective of callbacks, I am facing a strange situation when I knew that myDelegate.Target contains the reference to the class whose method it contains. (I searched it on SO, however I excuse if I missed some thread already answering this)

For example

```
public delegate void TravePlanDelegate();

public class Traveller
{
   //Papa is planing a tour, along with Mama 
   public void Planner()
   {
       //Asking me (delegate) to hold a letter about PlanA's detail
       TravelPlanDelegate myPlan = PlanA;
       //Sending me to TravelAgency office with letter 
       new TravelAgency().ExecuteTravelPlan(myPlan);
   }
   public void PlanA()
   {
         //Papa's open plan with Mama
         Console.WriteLine("First Berline, then New Yark and finally Lahore");
   }
   public void PlanB()
   {
        //Papa's secret plan
        Console.WriteLine("First Dubai, and then Lahore");
   }
}

public class TravelAgency
{
   public void ExecuteTravelPlan(TravePlanDelegate tp)
   {
        Traveller traveller = (Traveller)tp.Target;
       //Here it should execute plan
       //tp.Target - A reference to Traveler class, which can lead travel
       //agency to Papa's secret plan (And exposes it to Mama)
   }
}
```

In this example, TravelAgency can get information from delegate about papa's secret plan too. Did I get delegate concept properly or missing something?

Comment: Is there potentially hostile .NET code within your process? Or do you want to prevent leaking API internals?

Comment: I want to use libraries like TravelAgency, but I am doubted that they can go into details of my own library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. Unfortunately, however you try to "encapsulate" your object- there  must always be a reference to it somewhere, otherwise it would be impossible to invoke it's instance method.

As some kind of counter measure, you can proxy the method invocation to a lambda expression:

```
TravelPlanDelegate myPlan = (args) =>PlanA(args);
```

This makes it less likely that any rogue code will attempt to carry out some ill intended operations on your code, since knowing how your code looks like in advance will not help it accomplish a thing.

Note that this does not ensure a thing, since the produced delegate still has a Target property to an object which holds a reference to yours.

Crackers which are smart enough can still apply reflection to the generated class and obtain a reference to your object.

**Conclusion:**

Only consume code you trust - it is not much of a problem in today's Open Source driven world.

Comment: Lembda expression is a way to reference a function to delegate. It doesn't  help to maintain privacy. Can there be some better technique, if I am a library builder or on the other end using that library.

Comment: Lambda expression is not a way to reference a delegate to a function - it creates an anonymous object with an anonymous method. This class will have a random name, and the method that will be invoked will have a random name. Note that due to the reasoning I have specified in the first paragraph, there could be no way around this.

Comment: Yes, you are right @Perry. Actually my comments "Lembda expression is a way to reference a function to delegate" is with the reference to your answer above. I go the concept you have given thanks for that.